# Best way to handle lazy loading when creating a blue/green deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm going to do a blue/green deployment for an AWS MySQL RDS instance that has a read replica.

One of the [Blue/Green switchover best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments-switching.html#blue-green-deployments-switching-best-practices) says

> Make sure data loading is complete before switching over. For more information, see [Handling lazy loading when you create a blue/green deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments-creating.html#blue-green-deployments-creating-lazy-loading).

The [document of handling lazy loading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments-creating.html#blue-green-deployments-creating-lazy-loading) says I can perform operations that involve full-table scans, such as `SELECT *`, to help mitigate the effects of lazy loading on tables to which you require quick access.

So in order to mitigate the effects of lazy loading, I do the following things:

1. Connect to the green primary instance.
2. Run `SHOW TABLES;` to list all the tables that I have.
3. Use a text editor such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to create a command like `SELECT * FROM TABLE1; SELECT * FROM TABLE2; SELECT * FROM TABLE3; ...` from the output of step 2.
4. Run the command created in step 3.

But step 4 takes a long time (In my case, it's about 6 hours) to run.

Is there any more efficient way to handle lazy loading?